# Jquery .ajax passing msg to click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm developing a small application in javascript using jquery but i've a small problem.

i've this function

```
function cercahq(urlvalue) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data: "do=urlget&url=" + urlvalue,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg) {
        var data = eval('(' + msg + ')');
        $("#searchbar").css({'background-color': '#C33'});
        // creates element
                var insertform = document.createElement('form');
        insertform.id = "insertform";
        var insertbutton = document.createElement('button');
        var insertbuttonlabel = document.createTextNode('Insert');
        insertbutton.appendChild(insertbuttonlabel);
        insertform.appendChild(insertbutton);
        $("#searchbar").append(insertform);

       $(insertbutton).click(function(event, data) {
             event.preventDefault();
             alert(data.title);
        });

        stampa(msg)
        },
    error: function()
      {
        alert("Error");
      }
});
```

}

This function gets json data from a php script and pass it to a function (stampa) that evals it and print it in the page, but i need to create a button outside the stampa function that tells me a value from the json...
So inside the success event i've insered another eval to grab the ajax msg and create the variable data that should be passed to a button element that i've created inside a form called insertform.

The point is: how to pass the "data" variable to the click function from an element created inside an ajax request success function?

Comment: To parse _JSON_, you don't `eval` it - that is dangerous and takes cookies away from babies - you use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Not to mention all the puppies that it kills!

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' variable should be accesible inside click function through closure, no need to pass it there. By passing it as parameter you override it as closure with 'undefined' value. So just remove it from parameters:

```
 $(insertbutton).click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert(data.title);
    });
```